# Why does the second thread get released before the first one, when they both called WaitOne() and were released by an AutoResetEvent?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, resetevent

Suppose that ThreadA and ThreadB both call `WaitOne()` in that order on the same AutoResetEvent. When the event is set, why does ThreadB get released instead of ThreadA?

I ran a test to find out what happens when you set an AutoResetEvent on which mutiple threads are waiting:

```
    private static void Test()
    {
        // two threads - waiting for the same autoreset event
        // start it unset i.e. closed i.e. anything calling WaitOne() will block
        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteSomeMessageToTheConsole));
        thread1.Start();  // this will now block until we set the event

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteSomeOtherMessageToTheConsole));
        thread2.Start();  // this will now also block until we set the event

        // simulate some other stuff
        Console.WriteLine("Doing stuff...");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Stuff done.");

        // set the event - I thought this would mean both waiting threads are allowed to continue
        // BUT thread2 runs and thread1 stays blocked indefinitely
        // So I guess I was wrong and that Set only releases one thread in WaitOne()?
        // And why thread2 first?
        autoEvent1.Set();
    }
```

The code is of course not useful, it's just a simple example.

Comment: Try to call autoEvent1.Set(); again to see whether the other thread will be released. I think you need turn the switch twice.

Comment: Hi - yes I tried this straight after - I can get the second thread to continue witha second call to Set() - but only if I introduce a delay e.g. with a call to Thread.Sleep().

Comment: I'm currently more interested to see if anyone actually knows that the thread that gets released is random.  Documentation says threads get queued indicating some sort of ordering (which was why I expected the first thread to release first).

Comment: From here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx

There is no guarantee that every call to the Set method will release a thread. If two calls are too close together, so that the second call occurs before a thread has been released, only one thread is released.

Comment: where is the documentation :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, which thread is released by an auto-reset event is unspecified. As everyone else mentioned, you want a manual reset event if you want to broadcast a condition. If you want to release an exact number (say exactly 3 of n), then you probably want to use a semaphore.

If you really want to dig into why the order might be different than you would expect, take a look at "Windows Internals" or anything that Mark Russinovich has written. Chances are that he explains the wait order on executive resources somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN

> MSDN on ManualResetEvent: "Threads
>   that call WaitOne on the
>   ManualResetEvent will block, awaiting
>   the signal. When the controlling
>   thread completes the activity, it
>   calls Set to signal that the waiting
>   threads can proceed. 
>   **All waiting threads are released.**
>
> But for AutoResetEvent, MSDN says:
>   "Calling Set signals AutoResetEvent to
>   release a waiting thread.
>   AutoResetEvent remains signaled until
>   **a single waiting thread is released**, and then automatically
>   returns to the nonsignaled state. If
>   no threads are waiting, the state
>   remains signaled indefinitely.

"

Answer (score 0):

On an [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set.aspx), Set only releases one thread.  You should use a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) to release multiple waiting threads.

Comment: OK - thanks for the confirmation - any idea why the second thread gets released first?  Is it just chance that this seems to always be the case or is it always the last thread calling WaitOne() that will get released (and the others have to wait for another call to Set()?

Comment: I gather it's not how you would use it btw :).  I'm still curious though.

Comment: Seems logical since you block it last that it will overwite t1's wait and get woken by the set.  I.e. last one to block wins.  Not 100% sure of this, with threads, it's best to assume it's random. :)