# How can I reproduce one of the threads blocking indefinitely (following a post code)?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization, autoresetevent

I am trying to understand the question (and, respectively, the answers to it):

- [ThreadA and ThreadB both call WaitOne() in that order on the same AutoResetEvent - when the event is set, why does ThreadB get released instead of ThreadA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736310/threada-and-threadb-both-call-waitone-in-that-order-on-the-same-autoresetevent)

with attached below code

The comment in code tells:

```
// set the event - I thought this would mean both waiting threads are allowed to continue
// BUT thread2 runs and thread1 stays blocked indefinitely
```

But I do not see how and why any of the threads can be blocked indefinitely...
I tried to run the code and I cpuld not observer any indefinite blocking...

What do I miss in this question (and respective answers)?

```
private static void Test()
{
    // two threads - waiting for the same autoreset event
    // start it unset i.e. closed i.e. anything calling WaitOne() will block
    AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteSomeMessageToTheConsole));
    thread1.Start();  // this will now block until we set the event

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteSomeOtherMessageToTheConsole));
    thread2.Start();  // this will now also block until we set the event

    // simulate some other stuff
    Console.WriteLine("Doing stuff...");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Stuff done.");

    // set the event - I thought this would mean both waiting threads are allowed to continue
    // BUT thread2 runs and thread1 stays blocked indefinitely
    // So I guess I was wrong and that Set only releases one thread in WaitOne()?
    // And why thread2 first?
    autoEvent1.Set();
}
```

Update:
I was launching this code as:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace bothCallWaitOne
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      // two threads - waiting for the same autoreset event
      // start it unset i.e. closed i.e. anything calling WaitOne() will block
      AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

      WriteSomeMessageToTheConsole();
      Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteSomeMessageToTheConsole));
      thread1.Name = "1111111111";
      thread1.Start();  // this will now block until we set the event

      //Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteSomeOtherMessageToTheConsole));
      Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteSomeOtherMessageToTheConsole));
      thread2.Name = "222222222222";
      thread2.Start();  // this will now also block until we set the event

      // simulate some other stuff
      Console.WriteLine("Doing stuff...");
      Thread.Sleep(5000);
      Console.WriteLine("Stuff done.");

      // set the event - I thought this would mean both waiting threads are allowed to continue
      // BUT thread2 runs and thread1 stays blocked indefinitely
      // So I guess I was wrong and that Set only releases one thread in WaitOne()?
      // And why thread2 first?
      autoEvent.Set();
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void WriteSomeMessageToTheConsole()
    {
      Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    }
    static void WriteSomeOtherMessageToTheConsole()
    {
      Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    }

  }
}
```

And I do not observe any indefinite blocking.

Here is the output of having run the code:

```
Doing stuff...
222222222222
1111111111
Stuff done.
```

**How should I run (update, change, increment) the code in order to reproduce the discussed topic (of having one the threads being blocked indefinitely)?**

Comment: Please include WriteSomeMessageToTheConsole and WriteSomeOtherMessageToTheConsole

Comment: You have ommited `WaitOne` calls on autoEvent. No thread will wait in your code.

Comment: That's not me. I just copy-pasted the original post code. There was no WaitOne there

Comment: In the OP you mentioned at the top of your post I haven't see any method implemented as `WriteSomeMessageToTheConsole`.

Comment: Hamlet Hakobyan, this is my question - how to reproduce the problem having run the code. My realization of `WriteSomeMessageToTheConsole` is at the end of 2nd code snippet of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is eventual code to reproduce the problem.

Note that `autoEvent` cannot be local in order to be seen in other metods and it should be static in order to be used from static `Main()` and `Test()` methods and thereafter "used" from it static methods:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace bothCallWaitOne
{
  class Program
  {
    static AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Test();
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static void Test()
    {
      // two threads - waiting for the same autoreset event
      // start it unset i.e. closed i.e. anything calling WaitOne() will block
      //AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

      //WriteSomeMessageToTheConsole();
      Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteSomeMessageToTheConsole));
      thread1.Name = "1111111111";
      thread1.Start();  // this will now block until we set the event

      //Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteSomeOtherMessageToTheConsole));
      Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteSomeOtherMessageToTheConsole));
      thread2.Name = "222222222222";
      thread2.Start();  // this will now also block until we set the event

      // simulate some other stuff
      Console.WriteLine("Doing stuff...");
      Thread.Sleep(5000);
      Console.WriteLine("Stuff done.");

      // set the event - I thought this would mean both waiting threads are allowed to continue
      // BUT thread2 runs and thread1 stays blocked indefinitely
      // So I guess I was wrong and that Set only releases one thread in WaitOne()?
      // And why thread2 first?
      autoEvent.Set();
    }
    static void WriteSomeMessageToTheConsole()
    {
      autoEvent.WaitOne();//Cannot relve symbol autoEvent
      while(true)
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name+"****");
    }
    static void WriteSomeOtherMessageToTheConsole()
    {
      autoEvent.WaitOne();//Cannot relve symbol autoEvent
      while(true)
      Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx)

- AutoResetEvent remains signaled until a **single** waiting thread is released.

The AutoResetEvent works as turnstile. One call of `Set` releases *only one* thread.

Comment: My question is why isn't any thread blocking. Or where and how to put a thread into waiting!

Comment: @Fulproof Add `autoEvent.WaitOne();` before `Console.WriteLine` in both methods.

Comment: That's the gist of the question! `autoEvent` is local to the method where it is defined (and not visible outside of it)!

Comment: @Fulproof Declare it as class member or pass as argument to the `WriteSomeMessageToTheConsole`.

Comment: If I do this then both threads are being blocked indefinitely

Comment: @Fulproof One of them must be released after `autoEvent.Set();`.

Comment: Forgot to comment the hiding local `autoEvent` declaration+definition... Posted [eventual "working" code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15309201/200449) reproducing [the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736310/threada-and-threadb-both-call-waitone-in-that-order-on-the-same-autoresetevent) problem

Answer (score 0):

The ARE is a strange beast.  If you read the MSDN entry for it, you will find that, if signaled once while more than one thread is waiting, it will release only one waiting thread.  If, however, no threads are waiting when it's signaled, it does not keep a count of the signal and it is 'lost'.

It's a strange crossbreed between a manual reset event and a semaphore.  TBH, I find it less useful than either :)

Comment: I do not see where the threads was put in (indefinite) waiting, except the "definite" main thread's Sleep. And the main problem is that I do not even see how it can be done at all!!!

Comment: Oh - I assumed that 'WriteSomeMessageToTheConsole' waited on the ARE.

Comment: ARE in the [original code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736310/threada-and-threadb-both-call-waitone-in-that-order-on-the-same-autoresetevent) could not be used to put threads in waiting, at least, it (the local one) was misleading and confusing for me how. Became more clear after and thanks to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308657/how-can-i-reproduce-one-of-the-threads-blocking-indefinitely-following-a-post-c/15309201#15309201) and [discussion in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15308696/200449) with `@Hamlet Hakobyan`